# Android :: Service OnDestroy called very late

Tags: android

I have service with thread, From activity I am calling start service(from Activity::onDestroy()) and stop service (activity::onCreate()).

StopService() returned instantly but my Service::OnDestroy called after so many time, pretty late, Why? How to make Service::OnDestroy called immediately when calling StopService().

Activity class

```
MyActivity::OnDestroy()
{
  System.out.println("MyActivity-OnDestroy Start");
  // we are leaving activity so start service
  Intent svcIntent = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
  svcIntent.putExtra("SomeData", m_iData);
  startService(svcIntent);
  System.out.println("MyActivity-OnDestroy, startservice called");
  ..
  ..
  System.out.println("MyActivity-OnDestroy, End");
}
MyActivity::OnCreate()
{
  System.out.println("MyActivity-onCreate Start");
  // if service running stop it.
  if (m_bCalledFromNotification)
  {
   System.out.println("Stopping Service");
   boolean b = stopService(new Intent(this,AudioService.class));
   System.out.println("Stopping Service, Status="+b);
  }
  System.out.println("MyActivity-onCreate End");      
}
```

Service class

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
{
    return null;
}

// When service is created
@Override
public void onCreate() 
{
    // initialize service data
    System.out.println("MyService Created");    
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() 
{
    System.out.println("In MyService::onDestroy");
    m_UIUpdater.interrupt();
    System.out.println("In MyService::onDestroy, updater thread interrupted");
    ..
    System.out.println("My Service Stopped");
}

// This is the old onStart method that will be called on the pre-2.0
// platform.  On 2.0 or later we override onStartCommand() so this
// method will not be called.
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) 
{
    StartupHandler(intent,startId);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{
    StartupHandler(intent,startId);
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}

public void StartupHandler(Intent intent, int startid) 
{
    // send notification 
    System.out.println("In MyService::StartupHandler, Sending notification");

    // start thread 
    m_UIUpdater = new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {
        public void run() 
        {
            System.out.println("In MyService::Thread::Run");
            while (!Thread.interrupted())
            {
                // check update
                System.out.println("In MyService::Thread::Run::got update and loop for next update");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now here is output of logcat which show how late MyService::OnDestroy called.

```
12-17 09:25:44.462: INFO/System.out(314): MyActivity-OnDestroy Start
..
12-17 09:25:44.493: INFO/System.out(314): MyActivity-OnDestroy, startservice called
..
12-17 09:25:51.102: INFO/System.out(314): MyActivity-OnDestroy, End 
12-17 09:25:51.153: INFO/System.out(314): MyService Created
12-17 09:25:51.172: INFO/System.out(314): In MyService::StartupHandler, Sending notification
12-17 09:25:51.273: INFO/System.out(314): In MyService::Thread::Run
12-17 09:25:51.302: INFO/System.out(314): In MyService::Thread::Run::got update and loop for next update
..
..
..
12-17 09:25:59.903: INFO/System.out(314): MyActivity-onCreate Start
..
12-17 09:26:00.461: INFO/System.out(314): Stopping Service
12-17 09:26:00.471: INFO/System.out(314): Stopping Service, Status=true
12-17 09:26:01.363: INFO/System.out(314): MyActivity-onCreate End
12-17 09:26:01.421: INFO/System.out(314): In MyService::OnDestroy
12-17 09:26:01.421: INFO/System.out(314): In MyService::OnDestroy, updater interrupted
12-17 09:26:01.591: INFO/System.out(314): My Service Stopped
```

Have i implemented service code correctly?

How can i wait for service to destroy gracefully so that i can do remaining process after service has destroyed, like reading data service has stopped.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that `onDestroy` is called when GC reclaims the service.

Try `m_UIUpdater.interrupt();` in your `onStop`.

Comment: thanks but from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html        
The active lifetime of a service begins with a call to onStart(). This method is handed the Intent object that was passed to startService(). The music service would open the Intent to discover which music to play, and begin the playback.
There's no equivalent callback for when the service stops — no onStop() method.

Comment: @Markus, thanks. I tried System.gc() but still MyService::OnDestroy is called after MyActivity::OnResume completed. How can wait upon stopservice ?